# Python ipwhois ASN Registry Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, ip-address, whois

I am using `ipwhois` for the first time. Running the basic usage example with a Google IP address works:

```
from ipwhois import IPWhois
obj = IPWhois('74.125.225.229')
results = obj.lookup_rdap(depth=1)
```

Any other IP address results in this error:

```
ASNRegistryError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-03afc25be9cd> in <module>()
----> 1 results = obj.lookup_rdap(depth=1)

~\_installed\anaconda\envs\geocode\lib\site-packages\ipwhois\ipwhois.py in lookup_rdap(self, inc_raw, retry_count, depth, excluded_entities, bootstrap, rate_limit_timeout, asn_alts, extra_org_map, inc_nir, nir_field_list, asn_methods, get_asn_description)
    306                 inc_raw=inc_raw, retry_count=retry_count, asn_alts=asn_alts,
    307                 extra_org_map=extra_org_map, asn_methods=asn_methods,
--> 308                 get_asn_description=get_asn_description
    309             )
    310 

~\_installed\anaconda\envs\geocode\lib\site-packages\ipwhois\asn.py in lookup(self, inc_raw, retry_count, asn_alts, extra_org_map, asn_methods, get_asn_description)
    569         if asn_data is None:
    570 
--> 571             raise ASNRegistryError('ASN lookup failed with no more methods to '
    572                                    'try.')
    573 

ASNRegistryError: ASN lookup failed with no more methods to try.
```

I attempted to switch the lookup method to ARIN with `bootstrap=True` to no avail. How do I remedy this error?

Comment: I tried `obj = IPWhois('131.107.0.89')` with no issues

Comment: that one works for me as well. is it only top-level IP address holders (i.e. ASNs) that can be found? here is a Level 3 Communications one ( 8.249.59.254) that throws the error

Comment: Does your host has appropriate network access to be able to query RIRs RDAP servers?

Comment: What does appropriate network access include? It works with certain IP addresses, so I think it has access